# Notepad++ Regex - Replace a blank space in dates

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large export file from a legacy computer system. The dates that get exported have a `[space]` instead of a `0` for all single digit days or months:

`1/ 1/2015`   (dd/MM/yyyy)

The first space is not a problem but the second space is.

I have tried to search and replace `/[space]`  but this will replace any occurrences of `/[space]` in the data file - not only in dates.

I have also tried to use regex find and replace as follows:

Find:      `/ [0-9]/[0-9]+`

Replace:   `/0[0-9]/[0-9]+`

The intended out come should be:

Original:  `1/ 1/2015`

New:       `1/01/2015`

However I got:

Actual:  `1/0[0-9]/[0-9]+`

---

Is this even possible in Notepad++ or do I have to use MS Excel?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Find :** `(\b\d{1,2}/) +(\d{1,2})(?=/\d{4}\b)`

**Replace :** `\1\2`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kG5vF1/9)

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I also tried to **Replace:** `\10\2` which replaced the blank space with a 0 instead of deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try replacing `(?<=/) (?=[0-9]/[0-9]+)` with nothing (or 0, if you want padded single digit dates)? Works in Sublime, haven't tested NP++.

Comment: Thanks. The regex function worked perfectly (it found and selected the space) but for some reason NP++ did not replace the blank space with a 0 or nothing. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  was working perfectly in my editor.

Find what: `(\d/)\s(\d/\d{4})`
Replace with: `$10$2`

The explanation of regex and output can be found in below picture.
[image]